# Multiple Joins with QueryDSL

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I'm trying to use QueryDSL with Spring Data JPA.

My database has 3 tables.

1) An account table with account info and specifically an account number.
2) A PersonRole table which has a person's role on an account (like owner) and the corresponding account number and his person ID number.
3) A person table which has rows of persons. Their ID number and first name, last name etc...

My entities look like this:

```
@Entity
Account{
//...Other fields ommited
// **
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "ACCNT_NUMBER")
List<PersonRole> personRoles;**
}

@Entity
PersonRole{
String role;
// ...Other fields ommited
// **
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID")
Person person;**
}


@Entity
Person{...}
```

I want to filter the accounts that I select by person first name and last name and then use that to populate contract entities which have associated personroles and persons.

I assume I have to create joins to do this. I tried a bunch of things but I keep getting errors. I've created the corresponding QClasses. I know the below code is wrong and it doesn't work but perhaps you can see if I'm on the right track and possibly help me. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
    QAccount account = QAccount.account;
    QPersonRole personRoles = QPersonRole.personRole;
    QPerson person = QPerson.person;

    JPAQuery<Account> query = new JPAQuery<>(entityManager);

    List<Account> accountList = query
            .from(account)
            .innerJoin(acccount.personRoles, personRoles)
            .innerJoin(person)
            .where(person.lastName.eq("John")
                    .and(person.lastName.eq("Doe")))
            .fetch();
```

Comment: What do you mean by `contracts`? There is no code for a `contract` in the question. Also, why is there a `@OneToOne` association from `PersonRole` to `Person`? Presumably, a single `Person` can have a role in multiple `Account`s, which would mean multiple `PersonRole` records, one for each `Account` in which the `Person` has a role. Therefore, there should be a `@ManyToOne` association from `PersonRole` to `Person`. If not, why not just store the role name and account reference with the `Person` itself?

Comment: Sorry i meant account not contracts. I edited. So really there is a many to many relationship between accounts and persons so in order to solve that we use a join table. Although a person can have many roles on a contract, and on different contracts,  i thought by making it onetoone it would get a person for every role on the contract. Should i change that to onetomany?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need joins when you want to filter on one to many... jpql can still be leveraged... and I'd prefer to use a singular on the personRole so:

```
QAccount account = QAccount.account;
QPersonRole personRole = QPersonRole.personRole;

JPAQuery<Account> query = new JPAQuery<>(entityManager);

List<Account> accountList = query
            .from(account)
            .innerJoin(acccount.personRoles, personRole)
            .where(personRole.person.lastName.eq("John")
                    .and(personRole.person.lastName.eq("Doe")))
            .fetch();
```

Notice how the join to Person is not necessary.

Comment: You sir are a hero. Thank you for all your help! Now I just need to bring it all together with BooleanBuilder and I also want to use Spring Data Pagination. If you have any advice for connecting those dots I'd love to hear it :)

Comment: You won't be able to use spring data's pagination as you're doing joins in query dsl. Limit and offset are your friends. If you can figure out how to use spring data with a join then let me know

Comment: Isn't there a typo in the above where clause where `lastName` is being used twice?

Comment: yeah, it's in the original question...